# HTTP functions served from "firebase serve" hang forever with "error: SUPERVISOR clientError"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I opened up an old Firebase project to update its functions to the new v2 format.  No big deal.  When I did this, I purged all of my node and npm stuff and reinstalled it with `nvm` because Firebase was being very picky about the exact version of node that they support.  Again, no big deal.

However, now whenever I perform an HTTP request against a cloud function served with `firebase serve --only functions`, I get a crazy error message like this (and the request never terminates):

```
2018-08-14T03:45:56.195Z - error: SUPERVISOR clientError { Error: Parse Error
    at Error (native) bytesParsed: 1, code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD' } connecting=false, _hadError=false, bytesRead=147, , fd=14, reading=true, $ref=$, onread=function onread(nread, buffer) {
  var handle = this;
  var self = handle.owner;
  assert(handle === self._handle, 'handle != self._handle');

  self._unrefTimer();

  debug('onread', nread);
[...]
```

I pulled this from `~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/logs/cloud-functions-emulator.log`

And the error on the screen is just really confusing; it's dumping an entire file (or maybe `onread` function, at least) for no good reason:
[image: screenshot of error message]

This has been driving me crazy all night, and I'm still receiving the error after reverting all of my changes and going back to yesterday's code.

Has anyone ever seen this before?  Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you update your Firebase CLI?  What version are you on?

Comment: firebase-tools: 4.1.0
firebase-functions: 2.0.4
firebase-admin: 6.0.0
express: 4.16.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night's sleep and with a fresh mind, I see that I typed "-H" wrong in my curl command and instead typed "-X", sending my header as the HTTP method.

Was:

```
curl -v -X "Authorization: Bearer $token" http://localhost:5000/...
```

Should have been:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" http://localhost:5000/...
```

So, the `error: SUPERVISOR clientError { Error: Parse Error at Error (native) bytesParsed: 1, code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD' }` wasn't wrong, it was just super unhelpful.

Does anyone know which package that comes from?  I'll submit a better error that at least *prints out* the method that it received.  This would have saved me hours of time last night.

Comment: Looks like `HPE_INVALID_METHOD` comes from NodeJS itself.  I don't see any easy way to tweak the error message to be more helpful.

Answer (score 6):

That (very unhelpful) error message also occurs if you try to access the emulated cloud function over https instead of http. This can happen inadvertently if you have a browser add-on like HTTPS everywhere installed.

Comment: Because of this I will write better error messages... Thanks for the help!